# Angular4のベースとなるRequest URLはどこで定義されているのでしょうか

Tags: angular4

Angular4にて下記を使用してWEB APIを実施しています。

this.http.get(url)
[Angular4のHTTPでデータが取得できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38368/angular4%E3%81%AEhttp%E3%81%A7%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

上記ようなソースで、「InMemoryWebApiModule」を使わないようにしています。

実行すると下記のWEB APIが実行されており、

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/app/XXXX
```

ベースとなるRequest URLは「http://localhost:4200/」となっています。

環境の中をグレップしてみると、以下のような指定があったため、ポートなどを変えてみたのですが、
「ng serve --open」で再度実施してもポートは変わりませんでした。

```
protractor.conf.js
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
```

また、以下でビルドを実施、Tomcat配下に配置すると、
ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=none --base-href=/Test/
下記のWEB APIが実行されており、

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/XXXX
```

ベースとなるリクエストのURLは「http://localhost:8080/」となっています。

ただ、どこでこの定義がされているのかがわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpModuleの内部では通信にXMLHttpRequestが使われています。
`this.http.get('api/heroes')`のように相対パスが指定された場合、リクエスト先のURLはdocument.baseURI + 'api/heroes'のように解決されます。

Angularアプリがhttp://localhost:4200/に配置されていればリクエスト先はhttp://localhost:4200/api/heroesになります。
[http://localhost:8080/Test/に配置されていればリクエスト先はhttp://localhost:8080/Test/api/heroesとなるわけです](http://localhost:8080/Test/%E3%81%AB%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%85%88%E3%81%AFhttp://localhost:8080/Test/api/heroes%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)。

また、protractor.conf.jsはE2Eテスト用の設定のためng serveの動作には影響しません。
ng serveのポートを変更したい場合は.angular-cli.jsonファイルに記述します。

```
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {"port": 8080}
  }
```

のようにdefaultsの部分に記述します。
.angular-cli.jsonについては[Angular CLI Config Schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)に説明があります。

Comment: shimiteiさま回答ありがとうございます。さっそく試してみようと思います！